# Object tracking for velocity measurement

Tags: object, velocity, tracking

I am looking for a real time image processing to measure the velocity and output it to another control system.

I have attached an image of a yellow [stripe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKLDm.jpg). This has markings on the surface that I would like to automatically detect and use for calculation. In the first step the material moves only in one direction. Here for example to the right. For me only the horizontal part of the movement is of interest, so quasi only the velocity along an x-axis. But the material moves relatively fast. At maximum speed in 28 ms the current mark (spike) is at the position of the one in front of it.

The idea is to use a Raspberry Pi 4 with a camera at the maximum of 120 fps. So every 8.3 ms a picture is generated and should make it possible to clearly detect the movement of the marks.

My questions are:

Is it possible to process the images and detaction that fast to get the velocity in nearly real time? And which algorithem should I use for this configuration? Because it would be best if I could use two or three markers per image and average the velocity of them.

And I would like to use the velocity as an input signal for another system. What is the easiest and fastest way to send the information directly to another control system?